# Bash script strange behavior with echo - printf in a file

Tags: bash, shell-script, echo

I want to print part of the content of a .csv file in another file if there is a match with some condition:

The csv content is like this

```
abc test;ABCtest.it
xyz test;XYZtest.com
```

I read the content in a variable and I grep it for some string

```
csvContent=$(<$file.csv)

csvRow="$(echo "$csvContent" | grep -i "abc test")"

IFS=';' read -a array <<< "$csvRow"
name="${array[0]}"
url="${array[1]}"

echo -ne "\n$url,$name" >> "$outputDir/$fileName"
```

But the output file doesn't contain the url part

If I try this

```
echo $url
```

it's printed on the terminal!

I've tried also with printf and with an hardcoded filename but nothing!

```
printf '%s %s\n' "$url" "$name"  >> test.txt
```

It seems that when I try to concatenate another thing (a variable or a string) after the variable $url some part of this is deleted or overwritten into the output file

For example if I try with this

```
printf '%s %s\n' "$url" "pp"  >> test.txt
```

What I get with a simple cat test.txt is this :

```
 pptest.it
```

it is as if part of it was overwritten with a starting empty space

the content of the variable $url must be **ABCTest.it**

it's very strange

Comment: Does your csv file have windows line endings? If yes, the the value of $url will be `ABCtest.it\r` and when you use `echo -e` that carriage return will send the cursor back to the start of the line, and the comma and the name will overwrite the url.

Comment: Bingo! thank you very much !
I used this code to remove carriage return       | tr -d '\r'   and now works!
Thank you

Comment: You've found your answer already, but your script looks overly complex. If that's not deliberately coded that way, I want to ask why you have not just done something like `csvRow=$(grep -i "abc test" "$file.csv")`.

Answer (score 2):

You have carriage returns at the ends of the lines in your `file.csv` file,
and so they get read in to your `url` variable. 
And so, when you write it out, the URL data is followed by a carriage return
and overwritten by subsequent data.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a standard csv file like this

```
col1,col2,abc test;ABCtest.it,col4,col5
col1,col2,xyz test;XYZtest.com,col4,col5
```

You can use cut or probably awk.

`grep -i "abc test" <filename.csv> | cut -f3 -d',' | cut -f2 -d';'`